# What does Rusty's 'mini bar' hint to Benedict on the phone mean?

Tags: oceans-eleven

During the heist Ocean's 11, Rusty calls a cell phone that Danny left in Tess' pocket to get in touch with Benedict. Towards the end of the call when Walsh tells Benedict that the caller is in the casino by the slot machines, Rusty says something along the lines of "Of course I'm in the casino, in fact I'm staying in your hotel. I have two words for you: mini bar"

What does the mini bar hint mean?

Comment: I think it's just a joke. Like, you should put mini-bars in the rooms. I believe the Bellagio didn't include them in rooms for quite some time after they opened.

Comment: It's also funny because Rusty is constantly eating something in every scene, so of course he thinks a mini-bar in the room is an essential addition.

Answer (score 3):

At this time there is still no official clarification as to the meaning of the line. However there are multiple places where people have suggested one of two things:

The first interpretation is that they all stayed in the Bellagio while conducting the raid, and there were 11 people staying in the hotel at the time, all raiding the mini bar, and since they are stealing from the hotel, they have no intention of paying the (from experience of hotel mini bar items) incredibly overpriced bill.

> When Brad Pitt says, "Mini bar" he is referring to the fact that he is going to raid the mini bar and, (I think this is a safe assumption), not pay their hotel bill.

[Source](https://100hourboard.org/questions/6261/#:%7E:text=When%20Brad%20Pitt%20says%2C%20%22Mini,not%20pay%20their%20hotel%20bill.)

The other is that Rusty (Brad Pitt's Character) is constantly snacking throughout the movie, and it may be a real-world reference to the fact that they do not (did not at the time) actually have mini bars in the rooms.

> For quite a long while after The Bellagio first opened in Las Vegas, they had "not yet installed their mini bars". I know because I stayed there and tried to order a mini fridge at least, but they claimed they had not yet reveived their mini bars, and would be installing them "soon".

[Source](https://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101029105737AARv5k2&guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAIIxl_4-t2KQxHqSPFv7I9uQyQclsCyt2Lq6DXeK3a2lgqIh-Cs-86S5LKy-3T_jYZJOl_Cpfk8rRv0jjUPeUwt-9dUxXAOQz55UM7q-yiPSCDZiXRnDWXQ8OtfKeyHhyvp3vGFVgYbr5Yk8rYWno6mfQBf5GJgVKzTl4ESQLU6s)

Answer (score 1):

Rusty, being the wisecracker that he is, is taunting Benedict.  He's saying it to not only prove that he's been in the rooms, but to rub the fact in Benedict's face that he's one of the only casinos in Vegas not to have mini-bars in their rooms.

I used to be the CIO of a bond trading company in Greenwich, CT that owned a piece of the Bellagio, and we were among the first people to stay in the hotel.  I remember our owner actually telling one of the bigwigs there, "You know, you REALLY need mini-bars in these rooms..."